# Class for Switch statements

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, node.js, react.js, electron

This is more to get clarity on an implementation that I did. I am working on a React, Node, and Electron application that essentially has a form that a user inputs values that will update some content files.

The application has to scale for a lot of different scenarios so I found that I kept writing switch statements to incorporate all of these scenarios. So for the sake of time I wrote a class that:

1. Takes in two arrays, An array of keys and array of functions that correspond to those keys.
2. The constructor function creates a table for the values
3. Then there is a method on the class that allows you to look up that value and returns it

here is the code

```
Array.prototype.createObjectFromKeysandValues = function(array) {
    let table = {}
    for(let pointer=0;pointer<this.length;pointer++){
        let key = this[pointer]
        let value = array[pointer]
        table[key]=value
    }
    return table
}


  module.exports = class KeyFunctionMappingTable {
      constructor(keys, values){
        this.lookUpTable = Object.assign({},
         keys.createObjectFromKeysandValues(values),
         { default: () =>  new Error("Value Not Found")})
         }

     findHandlerFunction(value){
        return this.lookUpTable[value]|| this.lookUpTable.default
     }
   }
```

So when the code is implemented it looks like this ( this scenario is for React Components) :

```
const factory = new KeyFunctionMappingTable(['select', 'input'], [
    (options, labelText) => ( <Select options={options} labelText={labelText} />),
    (options, labelText) => ( <Input labelText={labelText} />)])
```

I am finding that I have about three of these "mappings" throughout the code.

What I want to know is if this seems like a readable implementation and does this make sense to strangers. If you dont think so please let me know your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have just added an unneeded layer of complexity to the problem.

You can just create the `factory` as an `Object`

```
const factory = {
    select(opts, text) { return (<select options={opts} labelText={text} />) },
    input(opts, text) { return (<input labelText={text} />) },
    default() { return new Error("Value Not Found") }
};
```

Then call the function with

```
(factory[value] || factory.default)(opts, text);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this. Should I keep the class or just use objects through out the application in all of the instances of this?

Comment: @GrantHerman Keep it simple and just use the object where you previously assigned `KeyFunctionMappingTable`

Comment: You may also want to add method that encpsulates the invocation with fallback to default, so that the `|| factory.default` invocation does not get repeated.